# Connect Redshift through Access Keys via SQuirrel SQL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-iam, squirrel-sql

I'm trying to follow this tutorial https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/awsmanagement-jdbc-squirrel-sql.rst in order to connect to Redshift via [SQuirrel SQL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/). In particular I'm trying to connect via **Access Key ID** and **Secret Access Key**.

When it comes to the *Driver properties* tab and need to insert the 2 keys, I struggle to set the 2 Values:

[image: Driver properties]

I try to click in the Value field but it simply doesn't allow me to insert any value.

Anyone had similar problem and resolved?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround by using a [Driver with SDK](https://s3.amazonaws.com/redshift-downloads/drivers/jdbc/1.2.43.1067/RedshiftJDBC42-1.2.43.1067.jar) (for other versions: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/configure-jdbc-connection.html#jdbc-previous-versions-with-sdk) and specifying the IAM credentials in the connection URL, so structured:

```
jdbc:redshift:iam://{cluster-name}:{aws-region}/{db-name}?DbUser={username}&AccessKeyID={access-key-ID}&SecretAccessKey={secret-access-key}&AutoCreate=true
```

and replacing the fields in brackets (the final part `&AutoCreate=true` is optional and necessary only if it's the first time accessing with the `{username}` user and is desired to create it as a new user in the DB (for other fields refer to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/jdbc-and-odbc-options-for-database-credentials.html).

I figured it out with the help of https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/generating-iam-credentials-configure-jdbc-odbc.html at step 3, based on their example: `jdbc:redshift:iam://examplecluster:us-west-2/dev?AccessKeyID=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE&SecretAccessKey=wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY`